# Box2d impact force vector

Tags: box2d

I need to get a vector from the one of two colliding bodies to apply it elsewhere.

As i see in examples and a lot of google-fu there are only strength calculation, not a vector.

I can get only `impulse->normalImpulses[0]` and `impulse->tangentImpulses[0]`.

And the PostSolve b2ContactImpulse holds the strange float (impulse is a vector AFAIR).

I'm really confused, please help!

Answer (score 2):

normalImpulse is the magnitude of the correcting impulse applied to push the two bodies apart when they collide. This is in the direction of the contact normal.

tangentImpulse is the magnitude of the impulse applied to simulate friction between the two colliding fixtures, and this is perpendicular to the contact normal.

You can put these together to get the overall impulse applied. I'm not sure which way the tangent faces in relation to the normal but in 2D there are only two possibilities.

Comment: Not sure that i understand which possibilities you're talking about.

Comment: If you have a line in 2d, for example (x,y), then there are only two possible directions that could be tangent to it: (-y,x) or (y,-x)

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 version, Box2D has one **important** thing:
You cann't do anything with your bodies when they are in contact;
Do your staff overriding EndContact() method.
You can Google for examples, hope It would help.